"Implement into" sounds wrong to me; am I off-base?
Someone I work with repeatedly uses the phrase "implement into," instead of "implement in." E.g, "We're going to implement this step into our process." (This is in US English.)
My understanding of "into" is that it requires actual physical movement; it shouldn't be used with a conceptual action. I have looked this up in numerous sources and not found a definitive answer.
Is "implement into" commonly accepted usage in any flavor of English?

This is techie jargon. And we can talk someone into abstract ideas.

Sure sounds weird to me, that's for durned sure.

The expression is frequently used in legal matters, e.g. "Any trade agreement that the president negotiates must be implemented into U.S. law by the congress".

There are certainly lots of uses of "into" which don't involve literal physical movement. Merriam-Webster has "enter into an alliance", "looking into the sun", "got into trouble", "go into farming", "not into her music", "far into the night", "dividing 3 into 6 gives 2", etc.

If you have a process you can either add to it (modifying the process), or you can do something within it (following the process without modifying the process). Maybe the OP knows which meaning was intended.

The colleague seems to be using it to mean "implement and incorporate into". I'm a U.S. techie and I don't think I've heard it before,  but the intent is clear.
